# Which are the technologies behind 2020 December Google Chrome game "Santa Tracker"?

Tags: google-chrome, frontend

This is the link to the game: https://santatracker.google.com/

Is there a way to know what front-end technology Google's developers used to create this game?

Please don't answer HTML, CSS and Javascript, I know how to develop a website. Is there a library that allows it?

Answer (score 0):

For making websites like this you can use python3.8 Django framework for backend, MySQL for DataBase, Html CSS and Javascript for frontend. Also to make easier your work you can use jQuery.

Comment: That's ok, I'd like to know how. Three.js? Don't seems to me, no canvas in the code. Other libraries?

Comment: don't use three.js use other libraries. If u r making html5 online game then use the phaser